# How download/upload contacts from/to mysql database using j2me

Tags: database, java-me, mobile

I'm developing mobile application which will be able to download/upload mobile phone book contact from MySQL database which is stored on the web. I need to get all the numbers, name, caller images etc from the phone (if it has) then store them on the database ans vice-versa.

Comment: This is extremely vague. You might want another look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you reminding me on how to ask a question in stack overflow, I'll keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use PIM API for retrieve and restore the contacts in j2me. see this [link](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/apis/articles/pim/index.html) for ur reference. You need to retrieve the contacts from phone or sim card then parse into xml format and then post the data into web server. On server side you can parse the xml string and get the contact values then insert the values into DB. Same thing you need to do on restoring contacts into phone contacts or sim contacts. for more into see this [link...](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/J2ME/PersonalInformationManager.htm)

Comment: now there is a little bit problem, as we all know that for accessing the DB which is on the web we need to host a domain and a DB against some money, but now I'm on a tight budget, so I can't afford the web, instead I was thinking that if I was able access my local http://localhost/ page which is stored on PC using the j2me app installed on the mobile using bluetooth or something. Is it possiable? please let know.